# BGE Sensor Message - get 2 Pulses

Tags: python, game-engine

I always get 2 pulses.
I just need one. Why is this happening?

This is my Actuator:

```
import bge

cont = bge.logic.getCurrentController()
own = cont.owner
sens = cont.sensors["Mouse"]
sens1 = cont.sensors["Mouse_over"]

if sens.positive and sens1.positive:
    print ("test")
    own.sendMessage("down")
```

And my Sensor is a Message in BGE Logic.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be your actuator. The BGE does not offer custom Actuators.

## Default sensor setting

(no level triggering, no level, no tap)

A sensor triggers all connected contollers when the status changes.

- from positive to not positive
- from not positive to positive

When you have several sensors each will trigger independently.

A controller can only be triggered once per frame.

## Level Triggering

True level triggering ADDITIONAL triggers the connected controllers as long as the sensor status evaluates positive. Consecutive additional triggers can get be skipped by the skip parameter (0 = the following frame triggers, 2 = the next two frames will not trigger, but the frame after this two).

The same with False level triggering, but the sensor evaluates not positive.

## Conclusion

You code looks fine as it is. (You could move `own =` short before `own.sendMessage` as you do not need this variable earlier.

Your code does what the build in logic bricks already do:

```
mouse sensor ----> AND  ----> Message Actuator 
mouse sensor ---->
```

There is no benefit in using a custom Python controller.